# Xamarin Android Emulator with Maps

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I want to run local test of an app using the Android Emulator within Visual Studio 17.  It works great using the Visual Studio Emulator for Android and the app is almost complete.

However I need to add a map with a few pins and I have this working and tested on my PC using the UWP app.  However trying to run on the Android emulator there is no Maps as there is no play store.

I have googled lots and found lots of things to try but none seem to work and I notice that the latest of all the pages and blogs I have read are dated 2015 so in software terms and indeed Xamarin they are very old.

So if I want to test the maps part of my app what is the best way if I can't get the Emulator to run with maps or am I missing some fancy new tool to test with other than shipping the app and hoping that it works in the wild?

Thanks

Cliff.

Comment: Have a look at Genymotion, it should have the Play Store and services easily available for you: https://www.genymotion.com/blog/2-10-open-gapps-widget/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the map as Visual studio emulators for Android do not have google play services installed by default. In order to test and see your map, you should install google play services in the android emulator.

You can do this by installing [gapps](http://opengapps.org/) on your emulator which provides you with google play services functionallity. The installation is just a drag and drop in the emulator. After installing this packge, you could use maps on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new Android VM in that process you can tell it to add the google store to the android VM [image]